# How to find all the tables impacted during a certain amount of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiler

My task is documenting what happens in the SQL Server Database when a user click a certain button. This "something" is pretty complicated and impacts (with insert/update/delete) probably something like 50+ tables.

I'd like to see that happens table per table but I don't have a practical way to know WHICH table to check. If I use the profiler I get a terribly long list of stored procedures names, not the single statements.

Is there a practical way I can find out which tables were changed in their content, using Profiler or some other tool, script or technique? Maybe there's a system table that keeps track of the last date each table received  an insert/update/delete?

Comment: do you want to find user scans and user lookups on the tables

Comment: just the names of the tables that changed in their data. I have the whole website published on my machine and the database is on my machine, so i am pretty isolated from external influences. I run the profiler, press "the button" and a lot of things are logged in the trace but almost all of them are StoredProcedures names. I should sift through all the SProcs and see what they do but this would take ages. I am asking if there's a smart way to do the same.

Comment: if any DML operations done on your tables in database .You want to list out that tables list

Comment: Create trigger in all the tables where all the triggers will insert into one particular table with the respective table name and time of DML operation.

Comment: Doesnt the execution plan help in this case?

Comment: Looking at sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats could give you some idea. As far as I understand it won't show you the updates to the tables unless an index is being updated too, but user scans / seeks should tell what tables have been accessed

Comment: "I am asking if there's a smart way to do the same", what you described is the smart way. Look at the the stored procedures and figure out what the code is actually doing instead of making assumptions.

Comment: Bernd, i think what i described is the slow way because there are tens of lenghty procedures to examine. With my way i found out 41 tables in a very short time.

@JamesZ: do you mean i should check different tables instead of the one with indexes?

Comment: @JohannesWentu I meant that you can find out what tables are involved, and maybe part of the updates / inserts, but most likely not all indexes are updated

Answer (score 0):

I though the best way was to search on google not for what i wanted to do but for *how i would do that*. And i found the following:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/

Here you can list the last time any table was changed so i check the time, press "the button" and then run the query with a filter that say "date last change" > time_I_read_before_pressing_button.

Comment: What will happen when one table doesn't have any index

Comment: Good point, but we don't have heaps. Honestly i can't find a good reason to use heaps in the real world.